# Getting a location in background while activity is changed in the foreground

Tags: android, networking, gps, location

I want to add location details into my application. I understand how to use locationmanager, locationlistener and locationprovider to get the location.

What I don't know, and I am sure this is because I am a newbie :), is how to allow the user to tick a box which says 'use current location' continue filling in some fields and save the 'form' and my locationmanager can either update the form if a location is found and the form hasn't been saved yet or go and find the form in my sqlite database and update the location details if it has already been saved.

I hope that makes sense...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think at a time, when user ticking a box this 'use current location', you need to start a `Service` which will run a LocationManager to acquire one's current location. Also, some object must be sent to a service. This object must have methods, which service will invoke to notify this object about location become available. Then, this object must act in one of two ways. If the user still edit the form - write location data to it (display in a view or smth else), if not (user is already saved the form) - write this data to Sqlite database.

Also, your activity must interact with this object. Activity must inform this object (with some method invocation) that the form is saved and set some database record's primary key (which is referencing edited record)